# How to move an existing line to a parallel offset of another existing polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I'm currently trying to modify an existing line to be offset x distance from another existing polyline, is there any tool/addon that does that? I currently use Copy Parallel and create a dummy line that I move/snap my line to. I was just wondering if there was any way to directly specify that I want an existing line to be offset parallel from another line x units.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Within the editing tool bar you can also create a new feature and specify [the angle and length of the segment.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Segment_construction_methods/01m70000005s000000/)

If you have the COGO editing toolbar available to you there is a tool called: [Offset Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000006v000000) you could also edit your sketch properties by +/- the specified distance (more math).

[The Copying Parallel Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Copying_parallel_line_features/01m600000025000000/) might be of interest to you. From the help: "Copy Parallel makes a copy of selected lines at a distance you specify. You can choose to copy the new lines to the left, right, or both sides of the selected lines. You can use the Copy Parallel command, for example, to create a street centerline or a gas line that runs parallel to a road"

Comment: As I've said in my initial comment, I currently use copy parallel and create a dummy line that I snap my line to.

That's what I'm currently doing, I was just wondering if there wasa  way to modify an existing line that way directly.

Comment: I don't understand - do you want the line to be offset and not parallel or offset and parallel? 
I don't understand why you have a "dummy line"

Comment: This creates a new line offset from an existing line. It doesn't *move* an existing line *to* a specified distance from another existing line.

Comment: The edit's make more sense to me now, I'll edit my answer another work day!